# Pandas dataframe to_datetime() is converting date incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date in this format - '17-JUL-53'

when I `pd.to_datetime('17-JUL-53')` it returns `Timestamp('2053-07-17 00:00:00')`

You could say it is correct, but the actual date to be returned is 1953-07-17. That comes out OK in excel, how do we do that with to_datetime()?

[edit] Just to show what happens when we convert from str to time in python:

```
>>> time.strptime('17-JUL-53', '%d-%b-%y')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2053, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=17, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0,tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=198, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add substring `19` to year.
More info about formatting of datetime is [here](http://strftime.org/).

```
import pandas as pd

s = '17-JUL-53'
d = s[:7] + '19' + s[7:]
print d
#17-JUL-1953
dt = pd.to_datetime(d, format='%d-%b-%Y')
print dt
#1953-07-17 00:00:00
```

`%d-%b-%Y` means:

> **%d** - Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number
>   **%b** - Month as locale’s abbreviated name
>   **%Y** - Year with century as a decimal number

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, providing all your dates are in the 1900 century :)

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
input ='17-jul-53'
output = pd.to_datetime(input)
output_clean = output - relativedelta(years=100)
```

Comment: then you got an issue in your base data I'd say : how you differentiate '17-jul-53' being 1953 or 1853 or 2053 ?

Comment: yes indeed. client's data, can't do much. But I am indeed grateful for the mention of this package

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you need to mention in which century you are ... in `pandas` this cannot be handled by `to_datetime` function, so you need to do it upstream. Here is an approach with regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

date = '17-JUL-53'

pd.to_datetime(re.sub(r'(\d{2}-\w{3}-)(\d{2})', r'\g<1>19\2', date))
#Timestamp('1953-07-17 00:00:00')
```

Comment: no worries, it's interesting because there is the trick to use groups followed by numbers, aka `r'\119\2'` do not work!